# How can I get index of elements which are not integer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In the numpy array (data) below, how can I get index positions of the non-integer numbers such as 4.5 and 6.7?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([2.0, 3.0, 4.5, 6.7, 12.0],dtype=float)
print data
```

Since I am dealing with very large array, faster processing speed is to be considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For speed you should use `np.where`. Now one solution to find if an element is an integer is to compare it to its rounded value:

```
np.where(data != data.round())
(array([2, 3]),)
```

Another solution is to use `nonzero`:

```
(data - data.round()).nonzero()
(array([2, 3]),)
```

Comment: +1. I was trying to work out how to use `np.where` but I went down the route of using `is_integer` which got me stuck.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) combined with the [`is_integer()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) method.

```
float_data = np.array([i for i, v in enumerate(data) if v.is_integer()])
```

This list comprehension will add the index of each element to the array if the element is an integer and is effectively the same as the following code

```
float_data = []
for i, v in enumerate(data):
    if v.is_integer():
        float_data.append(i)
```

Comment: The OP is asking for index positions !

Comment: @hivert thankyou very much for your correction D: I have edited the code appropriately.

Comment: the index position should be in the way the np.where function gives the result